# Laravel not finding database driver after php 7.1 installed on forge

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

The issue:
I have been upgraded from php 7.0 to php 7.1 on my DI box by mistake. Now laravel has been stoped working but only in case if I am trying to use it from web. If I do try to use tinker, or command line everything working like charm (also it worked on php 7.0)

```
#0 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(726): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from "...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(351): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from "...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1648): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from "...', Array, true)
#3 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1634): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#4 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(638): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#5 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(327): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
#6 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(297): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get(Array)
#7 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(171): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->first(Array)
#8 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(1126): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->find(327)
#9 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(606): Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider->retrieveById(327)
#10 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(544): Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard->user()
#11 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(492): Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard->check()
#12 ../releases/20170114080157/app/Poker/Helpers.php(51): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->__call('check', Array)
#13 ../releases/20170114080157/app/Poker/Helpers.php(57): merUser('check')
#14 ../releases/20170114080157/app/Http/Middleware/IsExternalAuth.php(22): merUser('external')
#15 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10059): App\Http\Middleware\IsExternalAuth->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10044): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8346): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8337): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8328): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2575): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 ../releases/20170114080157/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 ../releases/20170114080157/app/Http/Middleware/XXXMiddleware.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 ../releases/20170114080157/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10059): App\Http\Middleware\XXXMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
```

What do I missing here

I am using postgresql as a driver, not mysql
**Update:** Still not working. After a fallback to 7.0 everything is working again...

Comment: I may be wrong but I've heard people complaining about 7.1 with laravel as there might be some bugs around..

Comment: Could you let me know where...?

Comment: Did you installed the php7.1_pgsql?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install php7.1_pgsql` (not sure the name of the package)

Comment: Again. THe database connection is working. I can use it under console, under tinker, under the commands. It is seems to be a middleware issue, with the authentication service. I have been created an issue on github, lets see what is going to happen. thx for the help